# Adding a phone number to create account, and html style sheet

Tags: magento2, css, phtml, registration

There are few things I am trying to accomplish here, I want to add a phone number to the “create my account” form of my website, along with that I want to add a style sheet to my html that links to that phone number, (kind of creates a user ID, with phone number), would this be possible?

I am using **Magento 2** via `AWS lightsail`.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: hey, what do you mean by adding a style sheet to your html, do you want to reference a stylesheet in the head of the document? If so, do you have a theme?

Comment: Hey John,  Thank you

Comment: Yes, i do have a theme... but i need to attach it to my html under content-page (magento dashboard). I though if i can upload the files to AWS cloud 9 it should "link" to my html code but it didn't... is there another way around with with/without using cloud 9? maybe through magento dash?

Comment: do you know the URL you are linking to, it's definitely possible if you know the URL you're linking to, Magento actually comes with a feature where you can insert scripts & stylesheets before the head closes in your html

Comment: Hey John, yes i do know the url I'm linking to...do you know how i can access this feature? and are there related docs for it?

Comment: Hi, yes, When i get in to work on Monday i'll reply ASAP, i'll talk you through it

Comment: Hey John, Thank you very much, looking forward to your reply. Have a great day. Talk soon.

Comment: Hey Rav, you wanna go to Content -> Design -> Configuration -> Choose edit on the site that you're using (usually the bottom one) then under Design Rule choose HTML head and you should see a box for Scripts and Stylesheets, anything you put in this box will be inserted as HTML in to the head of your document. Paste something like <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/file/theme.css"> in there, save it and flush cache and it should appear in your head!

Comment: Hey john, Thank you, But i have a total of 7 css and js files... how would i get so many on there? would i add <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/file/theme.css"> to each one and in the body put the content of whats in the file?

Comment: like for example.....                  
 - so the file name is Example.css           how would i incorporate it in your example                                                                                                 
  (<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/file/theme.css">) and the content of whats in the file itself, (where would i put it)?.    sorry if i am asking too many questions my friend lol im not too good at this at all.

Comment: Rav it's okay, i assumed you meant a hosted stylesheet not something local, i actually answered this question here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/213286/adding-jquery-to-block-still-a-nooblet/213291#213291 but you need to change it to a CSS link rather than a javascript link

Comment: I've written an answer, for every single one of your CSS/JS files you need to do something like <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/file/theme.css"> or  <script src="js/function.js"/> inside your default_head_blocks.xml. I misunderstood your question at first, so apologies on my behalf. What I would say, it's never bad to ask questions, don't feel ashamed!

Comment: also I should warn you, by the time you reply I'm on holiday for a week or so, i really hope this helps you, if i've been helpful please feel free to accept my answer :)

Comment: Hey John, Thank you for all your help so far, hope you enjoy your time off. when you do come back I have another question.... how to i access the said path(CSS inside web/css, vendor/theme/magento_theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml)? I am using Magento 2 Via AWs Lightsail. I have installed AWS Cloud9 to my instance. Is this where i go to access this path? Thank you.

Comment: hey John, I did as you asked and went into the other link you sent to me( magento.stackexchange.com/questions/213286/…). seems like nothing is happening. Must be doing something wrong.when i try to test and run file i get---process exited with code: 127

Comment: where are you editing your files? Often most developers will have software like PHP storm, connected to VCS (Git) which will when configured correctly show you this tree. What editor are you using?

Comment: also what do you mean running the file? you need to save it, flush cache, open the webpage and go to view page source

Comment: Hey John, Welcome back.... hope you had a good trip. is there a way for me to pm you? or if you like you can pm me so i can show you some screen shots of what i have. I think i have figured out what the problem is. I have to turn on Developer mode for this to take place (I know you have mentioned this to me before) i am following http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-mode.html, and this ( You have to obtain SSH credentials.

 

Once logged in go to magento root folder and run:

 

php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer)

Comment: but see my problem is.... I have no idea where to go and run root folder, i have access to SSH to my instance via lightsail.... and i have access to all "editing the file, and the file tree" via AWS cloud 9---(found this image) https://docs.c9.io/docs/workspace-resizing this is what it looks like. Thank you John hope you can see the picture that i am working with? Thank you.

Comment: I got into my root folder by typing in sudo su on my lightsail ssh, but when i typed in:

 

php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
 it didn't work.

 

came back as "could not open input file: bin/magento"
also typed in "php bin/magento setup:deploy:mode:set developer" no change, also i went to my aws cloud 9 for my file tree and found app/etc, but not env.php, do i have to create the env.php myself?
Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: i don't know how to PM people uhm yeah the trip was good. I'm really confused as to your set up. A few things I guess:
A) What editor are you using? Your editor should provide a picture of your Magento tree, of which i have referenced 
B) Do you have access to say, a copy of what's on your server you can work on from your local PC? I would highly recommend looking in to setting up wampserver and having a local version of your AWS server to work on, that way you don't need to make the changes live. You need to look in to setting up a localhost version of your store, with all the files

Comment: and everything that's on your server. I don't have any experience with lightsail and so i'm very confused as to what's going on with that, please ask a question/(Or find the question if it already exists) about using lightsail to set up a magento development environment, and don't forget about asking how to set up VCS (Version Control Systems) with that. The situation you describe to me is very difficult to work out what's going on without being there

Comment: I don't think you're meant to directly edit files through the  AWS cloud, you're meant to, as far as i can tell, set up a bitbucket account, create a Version control system and link it between your desktop and the cloud, so you can 'Push' the changes you make on your PC to the cloud without manually editing these files.  It took me a LONG while to understand Git and Version Control and i sincerely reccomend you googling and looking in to that if you havent heard of it before

Comment: As I said, to me at least, it's very difficult to help you with the scenario you describe and i seriously reccomend reaching out to someone geographically locally to come and help you set it up, it's what i had to do when i first started because it really is a lot to try and get your head round

Comment: I use windows so it's the only metaphor i can use, what you should be doing is essentially making the changes i describe in my documents, on your localhost website (using Wampserver or XAMP or any other localhost providing-system) and then pushing the changes to AWS once you're happy with them, you should not be using AWS to make changes as it's very difficult and long winded

Comment: I can't really offer much more advice than that, i would only reccomend setting up a VCS system using a bitbucket account to host your projects and then using git VCS to push your changes to AWS. If what I said just then doesn't make any sense then you're doing it wrong/need to re-do your development environment

Comment: Hey John, Thank you for getting back to me.. Also thank you for all your help this far. I will follow the instructions that you gave me. Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my conversation in the comments with you You're going to need to go to paste your CSS inside web/css and call it something like, lets say function.css. Save this inside that folder, next go to Vendor/Theme and if there's a Magento_Theme folder there go inside layout and click on default_head_blocks.xml. If not, you will need to create this file structure. (vendor/theme/magento_theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml). Inside here you're going to want to insert `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/file/theme.css">` line just after

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
```

if you're making this file you then want to write

```
    </head>
</page>
```

after it. Save, flush cache and reload the page and the file should be referenced in your head. I hope I've helped